# Ballpark-only transform in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How can I address the below error when I trying to create elevation maps from a Raster DEM file?

> An alternative, ballpark-only transform was used when transforming
> coordinates between EPSG:3400 - NAD83 / Alberta 10-TM (Forest) and
> EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. The results may not match those obtained by using
> the preferred operation: Possibly an incorrect choice of operation was
> made for transformations between these reference systems. Check the
> Project Properties and ensure that the selected transform operations
> are applicable over the whole extent of the current project.

I am new to QGIS and not sure how to perform this transform.

Comment: We definitely need more details on this one. What exactly did you do? What was/is your goal?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361205/ballpark-transformation-message-error-for-osgb and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357269/qgis-warning-ballpark-transform-from